# Function to read a file and return a double array in C Code

Tags: arrays, c, double

I was writing a function to read a text file and return a double array. The function takes an input of the file name and reads the values therein to return the same as an array.

However, the function caller leads to an error of `error: assignment to expression with array type`.

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <string.h>
# include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_LINES 300
#define MAX_LEN 100

double new_double[300] ;

double fileopener(char *fileinput)
{

    char data[MAX_LINES][MAX_LEN] ;

    FILE *file ;
    
    file = fopen(fileinput, "r") ;

    if ( file == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error opening file yo\n") ;
    }

    int line = 0 ;

    while ( !feof(file) && !ferror(file) )
        if (fgets(data[line], MAX_LEN, file) != NULL )
        {
            new_double[line] = strtod(data[line], NULL) ;
            printf("The double value read is: %f\n", new_double[line]) ;
            line++ ;
        }

    fclose(file) ;

    printf("Done\n\n") ;

    return new_double;  
}

int main(){
    double t[300] ;
    char *filename = "AbsTime_v.txt" ;

    t = fileopener(filename) ;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Could you please point out what I have missed.

Comment: Aside: You aren't supposed to read from a `FILE *` if it is `NULL`.

Comment: You can't assign to an array. You could use a pointer instead, but since the array that is returned is global I don't see the point, just forget returning anything and use the global. You might consider that outside of the function you don't know how many doubles were stored in the global array and you have no protection to avoid going past the end of that array while reading.

Comment: OT: after printing `Error opening file` you should quit and not continue

Comment: Thanks for the inputs @RetiredNinja and everyone. I shall keep it in mind.

Comment: `fgets(data[line],  ...` You do not do anything with `data` after you converted the number in each line. There is no need to make `data` a 2D array. You can just use a single buffer for 1 line and reuse it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can't return a `double*` from a function with `double` return type.
- Even if changed, returning a pointer to a global variable is horrible practice to begin with. Instead use called allocation where the caller passes along an allocated buffer as one of the parameters.
- `t = fileopener(filename) ;` it is impossible to use assignment for array types in C. That's just how the language is. Again, `t` should have been passed as a parameter instead, for the function to fill up.

Comment: Is there any good reason behind arrays being non-modifiable lvalues?

Comment: @Haris Not as far as I know. Could be something that C inherited from B or BCPL... I can't find anything about it in [The Development of the C Language](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html).

Comment: This method of having the function fill out t sounds very good. I shall try the same. Thanks for the input!